# how to use components in knockoutjs using foreach

Tags: knockout.js

I have this sample component usage using foreach, this is my component in html:

```
<followers params="value:followers"></followers>
```

in js:

```
ko.components.register("followers", {
viewModel: function (params) {
    this.listValue = params.value();
    console.log(this.listValue);
},
template:"<ul class='list-inline friends-list' data-bind='foreach:listValue'><li data-bind='text:person'></li></ul>"});
```

see the full script in here https://jsfiddle.net/comfreakph/em0u592c/

the data in list is empty.

help thanks.

Comment: So, you didn't ask a question. Also the code at jsfiddle is substantially different from the code you posted here... it would not be possible to establish the cause of the bug here because it's related to an `image` field that you didn't even put in the code above.

Comment: oh sorry, i tried to update the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding image property and its missing from the data set, add it and it will work

```
 self.followers = ko.observableArray([
     { "person": "John Doe", image: '' },
    { "person": "Peter Mark", image: '' },
    {"person": "John Paul", image: ''}
 ]);
```

I've updated your code and now its working, check here:https://jsfiddle.net/em0u592c/6/

One more thing i've noticed in your fiddle code is wrong data "person:": "John Doe". You have extra column in person.